# What exactly happened to get the Mages Guild Disbanded?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

I see bits of text saying that the College of Winterhold was not affected by the disbanding of the Mages Guild.

But what is the story of the disbanding of the Mages Guild?  What happened?  Why was it disbanded?  (For example, did they do something treasonous? And if so, what was it?)

Answer (score 11):

They were in-part blamed for the Oblivion Crisis, which caused havoc all over Cyrodiil. Of course they didnt have anything to do with it but the people had to blame somebody.

Comment: Is that from an in-game book?

Comment: I remember hearing someone mention it in game, but I have no clue who.

Comment: I can't remember who either, but I think it's the Arch Mage when you first join.

Comment: For the record, we learned that the Guild was disbanded in the book "The Infernal City", which takes place in 4E40, only 40 years after the Oblivion crisis, so it is very probable that they were indeed blamed for it.

Comment: And the College of Winterhold was blamed for the Great Collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Mages' Guild got partly blamed for the oblivion crisis. The man who started the Mages' guild Vanus Galerion was also against necromancy. So that was not the reason for it disbanding. But when Hannibal stood against it... the mages' guild got a lot of enemies that wanted to tear it down. Also inner conflict happened in the guild after the oblivion crisis. So the guild exists still.. but now has two different organisations, with less influence.

Answer (score -6):

The reason why this has happened was because the Mages Guild  violated their charter by banning Necromancy. The Mages Guild was funded to train ALL mages in their arts, no matter what. So, you see, by banning necromancy they violated that charter. Hence, it was shut down.

Comment: Not to say that I don't believe you, but... I don't believe you. If you can provide a source, I'll revert my Downvote.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz You don't believe him? You suck!